large data transfer troubles with ubuntu 24.04
I've just installed Ubuntu 24.04 on a Intel CoreTM Ultra 7 processor laptop, 48 GB DDR5 5600MHz, with LUKS storage drive encryption.
Mem / Swap:
total 48959129 / 0
used 2250472 / 0
free 45898072 / 0
Any "large" data transfer from external USB drive to the hard-disk ends up with Ubuntu freezing after a few secs. Same if the transfer is made from the Windows to the Linux partition. It happens both with graphical and with command-line transfer. "Large" here means approx 1Gb or so (namely very small indeed!).
From top I see that when it freezes, what spikes is the process nautilus with:
VIRT 2449956
%CPU 53.2
%MEM 0.4
This problem makes practically impossible to migrate data to the new laptop. Any suggestion please?

Do you have swap? free will tell you and us.  If not, you need between 1xRAM (minimum required for suspend) and 2xRAM. Please [edit] your Question to add this information.  Do not use Add Comment.

since when is 1 Gb large? open a 2nd terminal and have top or htop active and watch what spikes :)

@ waltinator: edited
@ Rinzwind: precisely, that's why I wrote large as "large"; the trouble manifests even for small data, like 1Gb or 10Gb

Could this be related to https://askubuntu.com/questions/1522212/large-data-transfer-troubles-with-ubuntu-24-04 , for which there is yet no answer?

I set swap to 100GB (2xRAM). Still freezes. Any help?
